# Does the inner product define a function?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\psi: l^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, I can't understand what this stands for

$$<\psi, e_j>=\frac{(-1)^j}{j!}\in\mathbb{R}$$

$e_j$ are zero vectors with a $1$ in the $j$-th position.

What informations it gives me on $\psi$?

If $\psi$ was a sequence I would say that the product is the standard inner product of $l^2$ elements, so the result is the $j$-th element of the sequence $\psi$.

Otherwise $\psi$ is a function, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$<\psi,x>$ is just another way of writing $\psi(x)$.Therefore the above expression gives you the value of the function at all of the $e_j's$.
Moreover, if $e_j's$ are the basis elements and $\psi$ is a linear function then it completely defines $\psi$ on the vector space.

Hope it is helpful

Comment: So $e_j$ are a basis of $l^p$?

Comment: What do you denote by $l^p?$

Comment: The space of sequences with finite $l^p$ norm.

Comment: It's a Hilbert- but not a Schauder-basis (in the sense of Linear Algebra).

Comment: @MichaelHoppe on wiki it is written "The spaces $c_0$ and $ℓ^p$ (for 1 ≤ p < ∞) have a canonical unconditional Schauder basis $\{e_i | i = 1, 2,…\}$, where $e_i$ is the sequence which is zero but for a $1$ in the i-th entry."

Comment: Ups, my fault: replace "Schauder" by "Hamel", please.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe ah ok, so how to determine the dual norm of $\psi$? It is defined as the sup of $|T(x)|/||x||$, but it is correct to compute the numerator and denominator using the values of the $\psi$ at all the $e_j$'s ? What about the other values that $\psi$ can take? Is it that, since the $e_j$'s are a basis, so knowing $\psi(e_j)$ for all $j$ its like to know all the values of $\psi$?